# Error 3075 in VBA DCount Function when Comparing Dates

Tags: vba, t-sql, ms-access

I have a VBA DCount Function and tested all variations but i can´t get it to work, i always get the error (translated from myself):

> > "Syntaxerror in Date in Query:
>
> ```
> dbo_ABG_Wareneingang.Lieferant = 'Lieferheld' AND [Eingangsdatum] = #10.10.2018'.
> ```

The query looks like this:

```
DCount("Lieferant", "dbo_ABG_Wareneingang", "dbo_ABG_Wareneingang.Lieferant = '" & Me.Lieferant & "' AND [Eingangsdatum] = #" & Format(tempDatum, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
```

Comment: What is the datatype of column `Eingangsdatum`?

Comment: @Santosh date type in the connected mysql server

Comment: Query looks good. Try this `DCount("*", "dbo_ABG_Wareneingang", "Lieferant='" & Me.Lieferant & "' AND Eingangsdatum= #" & Format(tempDatum, 'mm/dd/yyyy') & "#")`

Comment: @Santosh still does not work, the ' ' around the data even bring an instant editor syntax error... i tried a lot im not sure why it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact, that in the format expression, "/" is not a slash by a placeholder for the localised *date separator* - which is a dot in Germany - and SQL fails on that.

*Escape* the slash to get it right, and make it a habit to use the ISO sequence, yyyy-mm-dd, as it works everywhere:

```
Format(tempDatum, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, "yyyy-mm-dd" worked perfect and fixed the problem.